# C# pegar uma parte de uma String

Tags: c#

Tenho uma string que caso tiver "-" quero pegar somente o que esta antes do "-"

var valor = "12345-485" ou "7896"

Tentei utilizando:
 valor.Substring(0,valor.IndexOf("-"));

Se o valor tiver "-" da certo, agora se não tiver o campo "-" me retorna erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode quebrar a string quando encontrar o traço e pegar a primeira parte(indice 0), se não tiver traço retorna o valor inteiro

```
var valor = "123-123";
var valorTratado = valor.split('-')[0];
```

.net fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1g9ZB